# Cast iron sewer pipe replacement

Tags: cement, sewer, cast-iron

My sewer line runs through our basement wall to the septic tank.  Due to shifting over the years the pipe has broken at the outside of the house.  How do you go about removing the cast iron pipe out of the basement wall to replace with PVC?

Comment: What is the basement wall made of ? concrete ? What is the pipe size ? how far into the home does the cast iron pie goes ?

Comment: Check this video : https://youtu.be/G-GFxdgMHAQ

Comment: With a hammer and a cold chisel. After you dig a hole outside. If you break the bell off the next pipe that's outside, you use a rubber coupling. If it still has the bell you use a ribbed grommet.

Answer (score 1):

There are adapters specially made for that.

Example

[image: adapter]

You will have to cut the iron pipe, and dig it out the ground.

You will have to feed the PVC pipe through the wall.

A good handyman can do that.

Comment: This does not address the question, which is about removing the broken pipe, not coupling the pipes after the broken pipe is removed.

Comment: @Ecnerwal maybe your German is not so good. The OP asked "How do you go about removing the cast iron pipe out of the basement wall to replace with PVC? "